# What counts as stdin?

Tags: discussion

Many questions specify that input must be on STDIN, but get answers in golfscript, brainfuck, mathematica, gnuplot etc.

I don't know whether these languages actually read from stdin, or can be persuaded to - and if they can't, should they be considered licit?

Comment: On many OSs outside the Win* and **x worlds there isn't a `STDIN` thing.

Answer (score 1):

GolfScript and BF interpreters are supposed to read from stdin according to their standard, AFAIK. They read from stdin and print to stdout, which is also required by interpreters, according to their standards. Mathematica doesn't redirect stdin - it lets the scripts read it normally, like reading from /dev/stdin in *nix. It also has methods builtin to deal with that. I'm pretty sure that gnuplot has some method, but it's hard to tell from its documentation (or I at least am having trouble reading it).