# PHP and "STDIN or an acceptable alternative"

Tags: discussion, answers, rules

I had a few discussions regarding *to use or not to use* `STDIN` in answer written in **PHP**. Reading from `STDIN` is very expensive in PHP consuming **12 bytes**:

```
fgetc(STDIN) // single character
fgets(STDIN) // whole line
```

---

### Different wordings in requirements

**From** [Implement a Truth Machine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/62732/41859)

> - take input from STDIN or an acceptable alternative
> - If your language **cannot** take input from STDIN, it may take input from a hardcoded variable or suitable equivalent in the program

[My answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/62907/41859) was discussed by [Martin Büttner](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/8478/martin-b%C3%BCttner) as I used a command line argument instead. [Another answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/63469/41859) ignored the requirements completely and the OP argued:

> I went for "or an acceptable alternative". I figured it's about the technique, not forcebly use STDIN. This is one of the very few 'keep the code shorter' tricks PHP can use, especially compared to the other languages

---

**From** [Write a Program that Writes a function BUT in a different language!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/63391/41859)

> Write the shortest program **that takes one input (n) from STDIN (or equivalent)** […]

[My answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/63429/41859) using `STDIN` was also discussed:

> Why not just `x=>x+<?=$x;`? It's valid PHP4.1 and you can pass the values over POST, GET, SESSION, COOKIE, ... and it will work flawlessly. Or on PHP5.3 with register_globals=on (on your php.ini file).

---

### My questions

Keeping in mind that `STDIN` is available in PHP.

- Do you need to read from `STDIN` in requirements like `from STDIN or an acceptable alternative` or is any other method acceptable?
- Is a command line argument an acceptable alternative to `STDIN` in?
- Is using `register_globals=on` acceptable?

If the last two methods are in fact acceptable, then all PHP answers could get rid of `$argsv[n]` and `fget[c/s](STDIN)` and simply use `$a … $n` based on the amount of input values.

---

This question is narrowed to PHP but the answers may apply for other languages as well.

---

#### Related

- [Default for Code Golf: Input/Output methods](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2447/41859)
- [What counts as stdin?](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1459/41859)

Comment: Don't have time for a full answer right now, but "closest/acceptable alternative to STDIN" is usually intended to mean something like JavaScript's `prompt()`. Specifically, I think that command-line arguments are quite a different way of reading input. While they are allowed by default, if a question specifically asks for STDIN (or alternative), I'd assume they have a good reason for excluding command-line arguments.

Comment: @MartinBüttner That's what I thought. Will post a feature request on meta.stackexchange to make comments acceptable. :D Seriously, if you find the time a detailed answer would be great as it is a very good starting point.

Comment: I think is safe to assume that most users will not have PHP5.3 or lower installed, on web server, with `register_globals` enabled - and won't take the time to set this up just to test a single submission. I think your answers will be less-well received as a result. I typically also assume `-n` (no .ini), which makes requiring a deprecated option a somewhat difficult position.

Comment: @primo Also a very good point. I thought similar when I discussed [this answer to "Summation from a to b"](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/60166/41859).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### You may use any acceptable input method

This means that any input that is allowed by the challenge (either explicitly in the challenge specification or implicitly in our [I/O method defaults list](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2447/41859) (so long as the challenge doesn't explicitly disallow it)) is fair game. It can be STDIN, but it doesn't necessarily have to be.

Answer (score 2):

In my personal opinion you should be using STDIN (with `fgets` for example) for any input unless stated otherwise. That's something all languages should do, that have the capability of reading from STDIN/writing to STDOUT. Also, on other golfing sites (like anarchy golf) PHP programs will read from STDIN. (see http://golf.shinh.org/reveal.rb?join+lines/yzx_1175413094&php for example).

If you want solutions to be somewhat comparable and roughly same conditions for equally well equipped languages then defaulting to STDIN/STDOUT unless otherwise stated seems to be the most reasonable way to do it.